# "Afin de" with many verbs

Tags: usage, prépositions

I'm writing a cover letter. What is more correct to write:

- Afin de parfaire ma formation et enrichir mon expérience professionnelle
- Afin de parfaire ma formation et d'enrichir mon expérience professionnelle

Comment: Consider in particular this article: https://rouleaum.wordpress.com/2011/03/26/a-de-et-en-celles-quil-faut-repeter/

Comment: @LPH thank you.